# Тире надо или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

*Крымский бензин самый дорогой.*

Нужно ли тире перед самый?

Answer (score 1):

Крымский бензин самый дорогой.

Тире не нужно, если именная часть сказуемого выражена прилагательным.

Тире в качестве авторского знака может ставится в параллельных конструкциях: Цвет коня – жёлтый, а хвост и грива –   коричневые (ударением выделено подлежащее).

Comment: Спасиибо, я так и сделала, не поставила тире, но все же сомневалась.